# How to deserialize and serialize AMF Packets in Python?

Tags: python, perl, adobe, amf, pyamf

I am rewriting the following Perl [code](http://code.google.com/p/get-flash-videos/source/browse/trunk/FlashVideo/Site/Nfb.pm?r=289) in Python:

```
  my $data = Data::AMF::Packet->new->deserialize($packet);
  $data->messages->[0]->{value}->[1] = $data->messages->[1]->{value}->[1] = $mid;
  $data = $data->serialize;
```

I would like to know how to write this in Python? I am new to PyAMF and the examples I googled wont help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
from pyamf import remoting

packet = remoting.decode(bytes)
packet['/1'][1] = packet['/2'][1]

stream = remoting.encode(packet)

bytes = stream.getvalue()
```